# Unable to install plugins in cordova project

Tags: cordova, github, command-line-interface, cordova-plugins

Am facing a big issue : `Unable to install the phonegap plugins` in my cordova project.Actually it was working fine still yesterday.

Now whenever I try adding any cordova plugin using CLI in my cordova project. I get the following error;

```
D:\Projects\test cordova>cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.network-information" via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.network-information
npm http 502 http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.network-information
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

What is the actual problem? how can i resolve this?
Please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is wait:

see this?:

```
npm http 502 http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#502

Error parsing file?:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

It is because there **is** no file or **valid** formatted json files to parse.

The server hosting the files is temporarily down. You could choose to report the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having the same issue. But when i tried the github version of the plugin, it still works.
Why not try using this:

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git