# Error installing Cordova - and blue screen

Tags: cordova, installation

When I try to install Cordova with `npm install -g cordova` I get this error (see bottom of post).

I have Windows 7, 64bit.

I tried installing phonegap years ago, maybe it's some old fuzz still in my system?

I also get a bluescreen (BSOD) if I write `npm rm -g phonegap`

**ERROR:**

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Eirik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\underscore\1.2.1\package\
package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Eirik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\underscore\1.2.1\package
\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
```

Comment: same issues!!please let me known if you solve your issues please post here

Comment: you are kind facing this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878044/unable-to-install-plugins-in-cordova-project while installing cordova. see if it helps you

Comment: I guess, my comment is too late, but still - BSODs might mean that you have some problem with your hard drive. `npm` is really stressful for your file system as it is writing insane number of files in `node_modules` folders, and if your hard disk has some issue which does not manifest itself in normal everyday use, then there is a chance that `npm` will cause the issue to reveal itself. I suggest scanning your hard drive for bad blocks and also using some check disk utility to fix file system issues, if any.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may due to NodeJs. Just [remove Node js completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) and [update with latest](http://nodejs.org/download/).
After installing latest NodeJS try `npm install -g cordova` again.

Comment: already installed node.js latest version still same issue please help